# If matched then print all using awk

Tags: command-line, awk, ubuntu-12.04

I have a file which contains many sub-sections each starting with [begin] and ending with [end]:

```
[begin li1_1378184738754_91]
header=7075|lime|0|0|109582|0|1|2700073||0|0|0|[355]|1|0|ssb-li1-1378184738754-90||0||LIME |0|saved=true|0.002406508312038836|0|[ser=zu1:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=uzu6:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzs5:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=sv-stda-zu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=hzu8:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=lzu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=yzu2:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzu7:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer]|0|null|false|40||false|
attrs=0|0|0||0|
ptitle=690751404|1|1|1|Rest:1998636||||||2700401|175619|900.5636134725806|0.985486|39.166666666666664|$9.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1998636|1|9.99|1|-1||0|||||true||4.7937584|10412|false|
ptitle=5543369186|2|1|1|Rest:1533891||||||2700211|19615|886.8211044369053|0.776121|34.0|$119.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1533891|1|119.99|3|-1|1.0:text,In+size+6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%2C8.5%2C9.0%2C9.5%2C10.0%2C...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2|||||true||2.95|20|true|
ptitle=622529158|3|1|1|||||||2700408|67402|796.5289827432475|0.893899|63.0|$5.27|100.0|1|||
seller=4281413|1|5.27|1|-1||0|||||true||4.695052|1769|true|
ptitle=5507199621|4|1|1|||||||2700220|56412|706.9031281251306|0.791171|45.0|$99.99|100.0|1|||
seller=4806107|1|-1.0|1|-1|1.0:sale,$,30.000000000000014,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,In+size+6.0%2C6.5%2C7.0%2C7.5%2C8.0%2C8.5%2C9.0%2C9...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2||||$130 $30.00 off|false||5.0|1|false|
ptitle=5502728013|5|1|1|||||||900000|0|698.7772340643119|0.836740|75.0|$40.95|100.0|1|||
seller=955448|1|40.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.142857|7|false|
ptitle=840662011|6|1|1|Rest:265238||||||300233|62718|683.2927820751431|0.995513|52.0|$22.95|100.0|1|||
seller=265238|1|22.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.478261|23|false|
ptitle=848084980|8|1|1|||||||2700073|145653|670.4809846773688|0.880587|60.0|$24.99|100.0|1|||
seller=5267046|1|24.99|1|-1||0|||||true||0.0|0|false|
ptitle=891200492|9|1|1|Rest:1030132||||||2701003|17215|668.8437575254773|0.825491|32.0|$519.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1030132|1|519.99|1|-1||0|||||false||4.7391305|23|false|
ptitle=641974054|10|1|1|||||||900000|69433|667.6678790058678|0.752129|57.0|$4.19|100.0|1|||
seller=3365158|1|4.19|1|-1||0|||||true||4.70907|4410|true|
ptitle=517591869|12|1|1|Rest:4802895||||||2700408|127644|643.0972570735605|0.893899|17.25|$23.95|100.0|1|||
seller=4318776|1|-1.0|3|-1||0|||||false||0.0|0|false|
ptitle=541549480|13|1|1|Rest:1180414||||||2702000|105832|597.4904572011968|0.752129|24.666666666666664|$8.27|100.0|1|||
seller=4636561|1|8.27|1|-1||0|||||false||4.8283377|734|true|
ptitle=1020561900|14|1|1|||||||2700063|159813|594.4717491579845|0.934869|75.0|$5.39|100.0|1|||
seller=4722645|1|5.39|1|-1|1.0:sale,$,0.6000000000000005,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+All+Orders%21,0.0,201301010000/,,,0,0,|2||||$5.99 $0.60 off|true||4.3942246|1593|true|
ptitle=507792308|15|1|1|Rest:4683455||||||2702000|105832|591.7739184402442|0.768311|22.5|$9.48|100.0|1|||
seller=4910651|1|-1.0|2|-1||0|||||false||5.0|1|false|
ptitle=1090571346|16|1|1|Rest:4452919||||||2700211|20824|776.4814913363535|0.776121|35.0|$59.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1533891|1|59.99|1|-1|1.0:sale,$,49.99999999999999,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,In+size+7.5%2C8.0%2C8.5%2C9.0%2C9.5%2C10.0%2C10.5...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2||||$110 $50.00 off|true||2.95|20|true|
ptitle=573017390|17|1|1|||||||2700073|91937|679.695660577044|0.880587|33.5|$14.85|100.0|1|||
seller=4281413|1|14.85|1|-1||0|||||true||4.695052|1769|true|
ptitle=5502723300|18|1|1|||||||900000|0|639.3095640940136|0.836740|75.0|$50.95|100.0|1|||
seller=955448|1|50.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.142857|7|false|
ptitle=940022974|20|1|1|||||||2700600|58701|569.9503499778303|0.875839|59.0|$14.40|100.0|1|||
seller=4825227|1|14.4|1|12||0|||||true||4.0289855|276|true|
ptitle=5513277553|21|1|1|||||||2700220|56412|565.2712749001105|0.776121|44.33333333333333|$129.95|100.0|1|||
seller=4825252|1|129.95|1|23||0|||||true||4.0289855|276|true|
ptitle=890329961|22|1|1|||||||2700408|133796|564.7642425785796|0.837916|34.75|$61.95|100.0|1|||
seller=4825235|1|61.95|4|19||0|||||true||4.0289855|276|true|
ptitle=753852910|24|1|1|||||||2700073|146738|557.7419123688652|0.934869|47.69230769230769|$26.99|100.0|1|||
seller=4722645|1|26.99|10|-1|1.0:sale,$,3.0,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+All+Orders%21,0.0,201301010000/,,,0,0,|2||||$29.99 $3.00 off|true||4.3942246|1593|true|
ptitle=654738989|26|1|1|||||||900000|84012|554.7756559595525|0.752129|57.0|$3.19|100.0|1|||
seller=3365158|1|3.19|1|-1||0|||||true||4.70907|4410|true|
ptitle=707747307|27|1|1|Rest:4736009||||||2700063|76249|552.234395428327|0.889614|19.857142857142854|$6.39|100.0|1|||
seller=4736009|1|6.39|1|-1||0|||||false||4.8071113|15356|true|
ptitle=63531001|28|1|1|||||||2700408|82712|625.0421885589608|0.893899|47.166666666666664|$7.69|100.0|1|||
seller=4281413|1|7.69|3|-1||0|||||true||4.695052|1769|true|
ptitle=5502728016|29|1|1|||||||900000|0|605.9895507237038|0.836740|75.0|$503.00|100.0|1|||
seller=955448|1|503.0|1|-1||0|||||false||4.142857|7|false|
ptitle=507792308|31|1|1|Rest:4683455||||||2702000|105832|559.6902659046442|0.752129|22.5|$8.99|100.0|1|||
seller=5105812|1|-1.0|1|-1||0|||||false||0.0|0|false|
ptitle=753852910|32|1|1|||||||2700073|146738|545.9987095658629|0.870929|47.69230769230769|$22.49|100.0|1|||
seller=4143386|1|22.49|6|-1|1.0:sale,$,7.5,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+Orders+Over+%24100,0.0,201109010000/201409302359,,,0,0,|2||||$29.99 $7.50 off|false||4.7316346|2355|true|
ptitle=5513277553|33|1|1|Rest:1533891||||||2700220|56412|653.3133907916089|0.825491|44.33333333333333|$149.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1533891|1|149.99|3|-1|1.0:text,In+size+5.0%2C5.5%2C6.0%2C6.5%2C7.0%2C7.5%2C8.0%2C8...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2|||||true||2.95|20|true|
ptitle=63531001|34|1|1|||||||2700408|82712|541.8233547780552|0.893899|47.166666666666664|$7.72|100.0|1|||
seller=2370155|1|7.72|4|-1||0|||||false||4.85|40|false|
ptitle=1018957017|35|1|1|||||||2700073|145653|540.6093714604533|0.860614|56.0|$25.95|100.0|1|||
seller=5036683|1|25.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.8405056|366|false|
ptitle=743682867|36|1|1|||||||2700073|63437|539.5985846455641|0.870929|58.0|$46.99|100.0|1|||
seller=193176|1|46.99|1|-1||0|||||true||4.8511987|1418|true|
ptitle=679858288|37|1|1|||||||2700063|188669|535.1360632897284|0.902031|30.0|$12.41|100.0|1|||
seller=4143386|1|12.41|2|-1|1.0:sale,$,1.379999999999999,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+Orders+Over+%24100,0.0,201109010000/201409302359,,,0,0,|2||||$13.79 $1.38 off|false||4.7316346|2355|true|
ptitle=994328713|38|1|1|||||||2700073|71463|534.7715925279717|0.870929|58.0|$1.29|100.0|1|||
seller=1787388|1|1.29|1|-1||0|||||false||4.680464|3624|false|
ptitle=886915818|40|1|1|||||||2700444|201835|529.7519801432289|0.934869|65.5|$44.99|100.0|1|||
seller=4561883|1|44.99|2|-1||0|||||true||4.7913384|508|false|
seller_hidden=227502|990765963|1147436601|-1
seller_hidden=5310958|622529158|5645627277|-1
seller_hidden=4825254|5543369186|5651114316|23
seller_hidden=5289138|5548930281|5653769481|-1
[end li1_1378184738754_91]
```

I am trying to run the command `cat /home/nextag/logs/OutpdirImpressions.log.2013-09-02 | awk -F "$begin" '{print $0}' | awk '$0 ~ "header=7075" {print $0}'`
As per this command i want to split the entire file into sub-sections beginning with the word 'begin'. Now in that i want those sub-sections which contains 'header=7075'

Expected output is that it will print the entire sub-section(those which contain that string), but i am getting only this portion as output:

> header=7075|lime|0|0|109582|0|1|2700073||0|0|0|[355]|1|0|ssb-li1-1378184738754-90||0||LIME
>   |0|saved=true|0.002406508312038836|0|[ser=zu1:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=uzu6:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzs5:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=sv-stda-zu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=hzu8:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=lzu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=yzu2:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzu7:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer]|0|null|false|40||false|

I have tried using if in various ways, but it doesn't works. Can somebody please help me. 
I tried `awk -F "$begin" '{if($0 ~ "header=7075") {print $0}}' /home/nextag/logs/OutpdirImpressions.log.2013-09-02`. It gave the same result

Can somebody please suggest that how do i get the complete sub-section in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this awk one-liner:

```
awk '$1=="[end"{p=0}/^header=7075/{p=1}p' file
```

In parts:

- `$1=="[end"{p=0}` if you reach a line, with the first word `"[end"`, then set the flag to zero
- `/^header=7075/{p=1}` If you reach a line, which begins with `"header=7075"`, set set the flag to one
- `p` if the flag is non-zero, print the current line (equivalent to `p{print}` or `p{print $0}` or `p!=0{print $0}`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can you please explain it a bit. what does p=0/1 do
?

Comment: It turns on and off printing of lines ($09) due to the last `p`  p=0, do not print, p=1 print

Comment: @vipin8169 added explenation

Comment: What @Jotne said basically